# Subtraction of CGFloats, ambiguity error Swift 3

Tags: swift3

I am trying to subtract some CGFloats, that are defined in this way:

```
var panelHeight:CGFloat!
```

When I try to do (screenHeight - panelHeight - tabBarHeight) in the following code, I get an error saying that I cannot apply a binary operator on CGFloat and CGFloat!, which doesn't make much sense, because all three floats are declared with !. If I replace tabBarHeight with tabBarHeight!, then I get an error called "Ambiguous reference to member -".

```
collisionBehavior.addBoundaryWithIdentifier("upperBoundary" as NSCopying, fromPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: screenHeight - panelHeight - tabBarHeight), toPoint: CGPoint(x: boundaryX, y: screenHeight - panelHeight - tabBarHeight))
```

Comment: start by extracting the expression `screenHeight - panelHeight - tabBarHeight` to a variable. It's possible that the complexity of the expression makes the compiler to show an invalid error.

Comment: I tried, but the errors are the same

Comment: I think this is a bug of Swift, better send a bug report to Apple or swift.org. A simple workaround -- `0 + screenHeight - panelHeight - tabBarHeight`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find the bug report, but this is a known bug. A workaround is to cast the first or the second variable to a non-optional, like so:

```
(screenHeight as CGFloat) - panelHeight - tabBarHeight
```